# Wrong plot alignment when using colorbar and groupplot

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, groupplots

The alignment of the plot is wrong when I use colorbar, see figure. How can I fix this?

Further I would like to know how I can make the small axis ticks black in stead of gray? Now you can't really see them in all the plots accept the lower right one.

```
|____|____|____|
0   500  1000 1500
```

[image]

```
\begin{tikzpicture}

\pgfplotsset{%
  width=4cm,
  height=4cm,
  scale only axis,
  every x tick label/.append style={font=\scriptsize\color{gray!80!black}},
  xmajorgrids,
  xminorgrids,
  every y tick label/.append style={font=\scriptsize\color{gray!80!black}},
  ymajorgrids,
  yminorgrids
}

\begin{groupplot}[
  group style={group size=2 by 2},
  y dir=reverse,
  axis on top
]

\nextgroupplot[
  xmin=0, xmax=1805,
  xticklabels={\empty},
  ymin=0, ymax=1200,
  colorbar right,
  colormap/blackwhite,
]
\addplot graphics [
  xmin=0, 
  xmax=1805, 
  ymin=0,
  ymax=1200
] {scarlett_dx.png};

\nextgroupplot[
  xmin=0, xmax=1805,
  xticklabels={\empty},
  ymin=0, ymax=1200,
  yticklabels={\empty},
  colorbar right,
  colormap/blackwhite
]
\addplot graphics [
  xmin=0, 
  xmax=1805, 
  ymin=0,
  ymax=1200
] {scarlett_ddx.png};

\nextgroupplot[
  xmin=0, xmax=1805,
  ymin=0, ymax=1200,
  colorbar right,
  colormap/blackwhite
]
\addplot graphics [
  xmin=0, 
  xmax=1805, 
  ymin=0,
  ymax=1200
] {scarlett_dy.png};

\nextgroupplot[
  xmin=0, xmax=1805,
  ymin=0, ymax=1200,
  yticklabels={\empty},
  colorbar right,
  colormap/blackwhite
]
\addplot graphics [
  xmin=0, 
  xmax=1805, 
  ymin=0,
  ymax=1200
] {scarlett_ddy.png};

\end{groupplot}
```

Comment: It's generally preferred to post full minimal but compilable example documents (starting from `\documentclass`, with no dependencies on files that aren't available to others).

Comment: Yes true. Sorry I forgot to add the other .tex stuff from my tikz.tex where I use \input{..}.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can adjust the padding between the plots using the `horizontal sep` and `vertical sep` options in the `group style`.

To adjust the style of the tick marks, use `tick style=gray!50`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\pgfplotsset{%
  width=4cm,
  height=4cm,
  scale only axis,
  every x tick label/.append style={font=\scriptsize\color{gray!80!black}},
  xmajorgrids,
  xminorgrids,
  every y tick label/.append style={font=\scriptsize\color{gray!80!black}},
  ymajorgrids,
  yminorgrids
}

\begin{groupplot}[
  group style={
    group size=2 by 2,
    horizontal sep=6em
    },
  y dir=reverse,
  axis on top,
  tick style=gray!50
]

\nextgroupplot[
  xmin=0, xmax=1805,
  xticklabels={\empty},
  ymin=0, ymax=1200,
  colorbar right,
  colormap/blackwhite,
]
\addplot graphics [
  xmin=0, 
  xmax=1805, 
  ymin=0,
  ymax=1200
] {scarlett_dx.png};

\nextgroupplot[
  xmin=0, xmax=1805,
  xticklabels={\empty},
  ymin=0, ymax=1200,
  yticklabels={\empty},
  colorbar right,
  colormap/blackwhite
]
\addplot graphics [
  xmin=0, 
  xmax=1805, 
  ymin=0,
  ymax=1200
] {scarlett_ddx.png};

\nextgroupplot[
  xmin=0, xmax=1805,
  ymin=0, ymax=1200,
  colorbar right,
  colormap/blackwhite
]
\addplot graphics [
  xmin=0, 
  xmax=1805, 
  ymin=0,
  ymax=1200
] {scarlett_dy.png};

\nextgroupplot[
  xmin=0, xmax=1805,
  ymin=0, ymax=1200,
  yticklabels={\empty},
  colorbar right,
  colormap/blackwhite
]
\addplot graphics [
  xmin=0, 
  xmax=1805, 
  ymin=0,
  ymax=1200
] {scarlett_ddy.png};

\end{groupplot}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```